# proper way to persist editable ag-grid cells

Tags: angular, ag-grid

I implemented ag-grd-ng2 (ag-grid for Angular2) with editable cells, and I am propagating these updates to the server.

I did this by wiring ***gridOptions.onCellValueChanged*** event.

my colum def has following properties:

```
            c.editable = true;
            c.cellEditor = 'richSelect';
            c.cellEditorParams = {
                cellRenderer: o => o.value ?  o.value.name : o.value, // use name property from underlying collection to show in dropdown
                values: list
            }
            c.newValueHandler = p => p.data[key] = p.newValue.name; // guessing this needs to be done so that newly selected dropdown item shows only the name in cell
```

The main problem with this implementation is that selecting an item from a dropdown will immediately update in grid cell regardless if underlying asynchronous call succeeds.

Is there a better pattern to use with this grid for updates so that value gets reverted in the grid if the call fails, or doesn't get set to new value until success callback?

another issue is that newValueHandler makes newly selected dropdown item appear correctly in the cell, but onCellValueChanged no longer has access to the ID field of newly selected item.

one possibility i see is ***column.newValueHandler***. perhaps there is a way to use that for an asynchronous operation and only set the new value on success?

*update, attempting this as a possible solution:*

```
newValueHandler(p, key){
    this.svc.updateProductField(p.data.ID, p.colDef.field, p.newValue.code) // async server update
        .catch(err =>  {
            p.data[key] = p.oldValue; // set the saved value
            return Observable.throw(err);
        })
        .subscribe(data => { $.notify(p.colDef.headerName + ' saved', 'success');
            p.data[key] = p.newValue.name; // set the saved value
        })

}
```

the update actually works, but the UI is not showing the new or old value, just blank. probably not designed to work this way :)

Comment: when you set a value of the cell, you'd need to call the `rowNode.setDataValue(colKey, newValue)`

Comment: thanks will try it now!

Comment: i think this whole pattern is weak.. because on success or error any update will trigger that same handler into a loop.. i'd need to have some indicator that this is not a user update.. the whole thing is wonky.

Comment: true, you will need to have some kind of indicator to track that. I think in my prev project, we ended up tracking that in the ag-grid's context.
Alternately, may be you can keep doing the update with `p.data[key] = p.oldValue; // set the saved value`, but setting the cell `volatile = true` and call `gridapi.softRefreshView()` after updating the value in the data?

Comment: @AnthonyC thanks a lot for ideas. I think anytime you need to store things in context or track stuff you're asking for bugs down the line so i'll avoid this like brushfire :) coming up with a simpler solution below..

Answer (score 1):

one possible solution:

Setting cell style to success or fail based on the server call. This gives some feedback to the user on what happened.

```
newValueHandler(p, key) {
    if (p.newValue && p.newValue.code) {
        var nv = p.newValue.name;
        this.svc.updateProductField(p.data.ID, p.colDef.field, p.newValue.code)
            .catch(err => {
                p.colDef.cellClass = 'ag-etp-cell-failed';
                $.notify(p.colDef.headerName + ' update failed', 'error');
                return Observable.throw(err);
            })
            .map(o => {
                p.colDef.cellClass = 'ag-etp-cell-saved';
                $.notify(p.colDef.headerName + ' saved', 'success');
            })
            .subscribe();
    }
    p.data[key] = p.newValue.name || p.newValue;
}
```